# Can I download Juniper predefined security templates for view, outside of my router?

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

Based on this page: [How to use predefined policy templates in an IDP policy in SRX and J-series devices](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB16490)

I would like to download these templates to read through them, but from my desktop. I couldn't find anywhere online to grab these.. only through the update commands they give in the doc above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've uploaded the template output for you here:

http://pastebin.com/iBx30XP7

Comment: You are a beautiful human being.